# how to setup master-slave replication over the internet?

Tags: sql, replication

I have few web sites/databases on cloud servers which I want to replicate to my local server
to have current data most of the time. What is the proper way doing this over the internet?
Should I use web services between?  Local DB is SQL Server, remote are MySql.
thanks

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com ? - see the related question answers popping on the right sidebar

Comment: I have found the closest what I need for now was Web Synchronization for Merge Replication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151763.aspx